# iOS const char* to std::string and back missing first character

Tags: c++, ios, iphone

I am getting a peculiar runtime error in my code on an iOS build with c++ code runing on an iphone in Xcode 10.3.

Stopping this code in the debugger:

```
const char* testChar = "testing";
std::string testingString = testChar;
const char* testCharBack = testChar.c_str();
```

const char* testCharBack prints

> "esting"

instead of

> "testing"

[image]

EDIT:
NSLog output is missing the first character as well:

> NSLog( @"testingCharBack=%s", testCharBack );
>
> 2019-08-07 15:53:53.451173+0200 App[499:108370] testingCharBack=esting

I am using the libc++ (LLVN C++ standard library with C++11 support) compiler and c++11 dialect.
Any ideas what might be wrong with the build or build settings?

Comment: If you print out `testCharBack` (with, say,`std::cout`), do you also print `"esting"` instead of `"testing"`?

Comment: what you get after NSLogging testCharBack?

Comment: You're showing a debugger screen.  Does the actual program work?

Comment: Looks like the program is at the line 77 breakpoint, and hasn't actually executed the code.  So the value that is seen in `testCharBack` is garbage (and just happens to garbagely point to `esting`).

Comment: @AbuUlHassan and @ jjramsey I updated the question with the log output. Because its easier to print NSLog I did just that. It strips the first character as well.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I tried to gather the "lowest common denominator" of the problem I am having. The answer is no. The program does not work it crashes. The thing is that const char* are converted to std::string and back a few times until the last std::string gets a null char string and crashes. I checked the scope of the std::string and it is not released before it gets converted.

Comment: @Eljay I was thinking this might be a debugger issue as well. But I think its not, even if you step over this line the assignement stays the same. Also the output of NSLog is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case it turned out to be the `__arm__` Preprocessor macro that made the app fail and crash.